# Filter one column, using another column as criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I want to filter Column B, using Column A as the criteria. I'm working with quite a lot of data. Column B is consisting of almost 90.000 rows. I have tried using the Advanced filter function. But I have some problems getting it to work. Any tips would be greatle appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to filter column B when value in Column A equals value in Column B?

Answer (score 3):

Excel's Advanced Filter doesn't work when the criteria range refers to the entire column:

[image: Criteria range refers to the entire column]

Change it to refer to only the range within which your data resides, and it'll work.

**Note:** Both the list range and criteria range should have the same heading for this to work.

[image: Criteria range refers only to the relevant data]

Comment: Awesome, what if I want to filter where $B1=$D1, $B2=$D2 e.t.c? Cell at B equals cell value at column D. Is it possible?